# SQL Server : replace several instances of userID with username

Tags: sql, sql-server

I may be overthinking this but I have not managed to figure it out or find a solution, so I'm hoping for a pointer in the right direction. I tried using the `Select ColumnA AS Column B` etc but it's not doing what I want.

I have 2 tables, scenario examples below

Table 1 (Vehicle)

```
VehicleID (001)
VehicleMake (Ford)
VehicleModel (Falcon)
VehicleExCleanEmpID (005)
VehicleIntCleanEmpID (003)
```

Table 2 (Employee)

```
EmpID (005)
EmpName (Dave)
```

The scenario being that a vehicle is cleaned internally or externally by any one of a pool of employees shown by the relevant ID in the `Vehicles` table.

I want to show in a query `VehicleID, InsideCleanName, ExternalCleanName` rather than showing the employee's ID.

So end up with results similar to this

```
VehicleID   InsideCleanName   ExternalCleanName
------------------------------------------------
001         Bob               Dave
002         Sue               Dave
003         John              Sid
```

Thanks for any tips and or help

Comment: You should put the query you managed to get until now and explain in what part of the query are you struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THat seems like a pretty simple query with two inner joins to the `Employee` table - something like this:

```
SELECT
    v.VehicleId,
    InsideCleanName = e1.EmpName,
    ExternalCleanName = e2.EmpName
FROM
    dbo.Vehicle v
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Employee e1 ON v.VehicleIntCleanEmpId = e1.EmpID
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Employee e2 ON v.VehicleExCleanEmpId = e2.EmpID
```

Joining to the `Employee e1` table is giving you the employee who was responsible for the inside cleaning, while joining a second time, to `Employee e2` gives you the one responsible for the external cleaning.

Comment: Ahh I think I now understand, you basically created 2 different aliases for the same table in the join statements, correct?

Comment: @WeirdMunky: exactly. Your `Vehicle` table has **two** references to the `Employee` table - so you need to join *twice* to that table, and the aliases `e1` and `e2` keep those two separate joins apart

Comment: Perfectly executed and explained, appreciate the help. It was the use of aliases that I missed.

Comment: @WeirdMunky: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Join the two table with EmpId and select the columns you want similar to the code below:

```
select column1, column2 from table1 inner join table2 on table1.EmpId = table2.EmpId
```